# I don't know how to classify JSON data in Android

Tags: android, json

I'm a newbie in Android. I'm making a crypto currency tracker. I'm using a Korean exchange API. But, when I read JSON data as String, it's a little different from what I found in literature.

In the red bracket, there are some data but are classified as the String like "BTC, ETH". And I learned in a book like this

```
String timestamp;
String payment_currency; // payment currency(USD, KRW...)
ArrayList<BidAskBithumb> bids = new ArrayList<BidAskBithumb>(); // Bids
ArrayList<BidAskBithumb> asks = new ArrayList<BidAskBithumb>(); // Asks
```

Every property is saved in String and Arrays. But in that JSON data, there is currency's name like BTC or ETH after payment_currency String. I don't know I have to make every class file like BTC.java or ETH.java. How can I solve this?

This is the JSON response I'm getting.

[image]

I read all the currency's data:

[image]

The original API documentation [link](https://apidocs.bithumb.com/docs/order_book).

Comment: Can you provide more information like what you actually want?

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know I have to make every class file like BTC.java or ETH.java. How can I solve this?

No, you dont have to create new class files for them, you need to create `model` class according to your json file. & handle its behaviour.

You can try [this to create your model.](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)